# How Can I permit nested attributes with active model serializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

I'm using [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/v0.9.3) from an api in ruby on rails, and I have a controller method in which i save an invoice and its nested items  with some calculations, the problem is that after include serializer, the nested attributes are restricted and I can't access to them.

I have the code in this way according to some documentation, but it doesn't works

```rb
#Controller

 def invoice_params
        params.require(:invoice).permit(:person_id, :date, sales_attributes: [:reference_id, :quantity, :price])
 end

#Model

class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :person
    has_many :sales
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :sales, allow_destroy: true
end

#Serializer

class InvoiceSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :date, :total, :profit, :consecutive, :person_id
    has_many :sales, root: :sales_attributes
    belongs_to :person
end
```

The json request that I'm sending is:

```
{
    "person_id": 4,
    "date": "2019-03-20",
    "sales": [
        {
            "reference_id":1,
            "quantity": 90000,
            "price": 240
        },
        {
            "reference_id":1,
            "quantity": 50000,
            "price": 240
        }
    ]
}
```

Some one knows what happen?, before of include the serializer gem it was working fine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please provide more information, like the error message. Use the bang `!` to allow the active record to raise the validation error. I can't understand what you mean with "restricted".

Comment: With restricted I mean unpermitted , and there are not errors, because I'm looping over that nested sales in the way of  `@invoice.sales.each do |sale| `, but them are unpermitted, then the each never starts.

Comment: @JuanParra please provide errors logs, difficult to trace what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
def invoice_params
        params.require(:invoice).permit(:person_id, :date, sales_attributes: [:reference_id, :quantity, :price])
 end
```

to

```
def invoice_params
        params.require(:invoice).permit(:person_id, :date, sales_attributes: [:id, :reference_id, :quantity, :price])
 end
```

and

```
{
    "person_id": 4,
    "date": "2019-03-20",
    "sales": [
        {
            "reference_id":1,
            "quantity": 90000,
            "price": 240
        },
        {
            "reference_id":1,
            "quantity": 50000,
            "price": 240
        }
    ]
}
```

to

```
{
    "person_id": 4,
    "date": "2019-03-20",
    "sales_attributes": [
        {
            "reference_id":1,
            "quantity": 90000,
            "price": 240
        },
        {
            "reference_id":1,
            "quantity": 50000,
            "price": 240
        }
    ]
}
```